# Is it possible to make a css3 animation/ page transition for outgoing links?

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-transitions

Is it possible to make a css3 page transition for outgoing links without using Javascript or JQuery only CSS3 and HTML5? Regards

Comment: Please show what your previous attempts at doing this were. You can post some code of what you've tried so far, or perhaps link to some sites you've found. Try doing some research before asking your question here.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want some page-loading transition such as the one YouTube has? If you do mean that, no it's not possible without JavaScript.

Comment: i want to make page transitions like these ones http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ but these ones are made with anchors. how can i use css transitions if i have to link a new html file?

Comment: That's impossible. You will absolutely need JavaScript if you want to load another url.